# How define jquery version with rails asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I use Rails 3.1 with asset-pipeline and I would like to use a specific version of JQuery.

For example for my project JQuery 1.6.2 is added by default but I would like to use JQuery 1.7.1

Can I specified it in my application.js? Or it's something to configure in my Gemfile (jquery-rails gem for example, my version is 1.0.14)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Seems the gem was updated](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/pull/30)

**Edit:** version 1.0.19 uses jquery 1.7, update your gem

If not, try this:

```
gem environment
```

Navigate to your gem path and look for somthing like `gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts` and replace `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.js` with jquery 1.7 code.

Comment: Indeed the gem was updated. Yet I'm not really satisfied because the current version of JQuery is 1.7.1 and the gem add 1.7.0
And In the future if I want to downgrade to 1.6.2 I will need to downgrade my gem?

Comment: Manually update the gem as described above to get jquery 1.7.1